# Printing left and right values of an avl tree

Tags: c, avl-tree

I am trying to write a piece of code that displays the integers as they are being loaded into a binary tree. I have written this so far:

```
node*t;    
t = NULL;

for( j = 0; j < 33; j++)
{
    printf ("Table %d \n", j+1);
    printf ("LineNum  Left  Data   Right\n");
    printf ("%5d %5d %5d %5d", t->num, t->left->data, t->data, t-> right -> data);      
    t = insert(j, a[j], t );


}
```

The program still keeps crashing though. How can I solve that? Am i going about this the wrong way?

**EDIT:** I fixed the problem pointed out in the previous comments

Comment: `left ->right` is pointer to a node not an `int` field of your tree.

Comment: Have you tried passing an `int` instead of a `struct node *`?

Comment: thanks, it compiles now but the program keeps crashing. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: `t-> left ->right` maybe `t->right->data`

Answer (score 2):

```
printf ("%5d %5d %5d %5d", t->num, t->left->data, t->data, t-> left ->right);
```

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

Do you mean `t->right->data`?

Comment: Seems it fails because `t` is used unititialized, try to print values afert insert

Comment: I tried that, still keeps crashing... am i going around printing these values the wrong way?

Comment: have you check if `a[j]` gives you a valid `int`?, I suggest you to spend some time learning to use a debugger

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as how for left you are printing `t->left->data`, I'm guessing you want `t->right->data` not `t-> left ->right`.

If you are trying to print the pointer, cast `t-> left ->right` to an `int` (`unsigned int` would be better)